# Convert varchar2 to date

Tags: sql, date, plsql, date-format

Following is my code sample. I need to convert the need_by in varchar2 to need_by_date in date format. The timezone information is where i am getting the issue.
What is the correct format string for this date format?

```
declare

need_by varchar2(50);
need_by_date date;
begin

need_by := '2014-11-24T04:31:43.967Z';
 need_by_date := to_date(need_by,'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:MI:ss');

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(need_by_date);

end;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How your date format should look? Would you want only the date or data and time as well?

Comment: Need the entire thing. Date and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select to_timestamp('2014-11-24T04:31:43.967Z', 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"') at time zone 'UTC' from dual;
```

(".967" is fraction seconds, "Z" is UTC)